# IBM MQ FTE: alternative open source solution requested

Tags: file-transfer, websphere-mq-fte

We have a need: to provide secure, guaranteed file transfer in our distributed network (Managed File Transfer-class solution, MFT). For that purpose we expect IBM MQ FTE to be ok. But it is quite expensive one.

So, is there any comparable open-source enterprise solution to consider instead IBM MQ FTE?